# Add datafrom textfile to excel worksheet and save

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

Hello There,
            I am trying to enter data from text to excel and save it under particular worksheet name. It works if there is only 1 worksheet but it doesn't work when I call same code again as it overwrites the excel file. I was wondering if I can copy data from text and add to worksheet. I have used clipboard method but it throws STA error. I repeat copy text file to worksheet again and again. Here is my code: help is appreciated.

```
 a_Books.OpenText(reportloc + ".txt", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 1,
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
  false, true, false, false, false, false, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt);

  a_Book = a_Excel.Workbooks.Add(a_Opt);

                    a_Book.Sheets.Add();

                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)a_Book.ActiveSheet;
                   worksheet.Activate();
                    worksheet.Name = reportname;

                    FormatRaw_Data(worksheet);
                    a_Book.SaveAs(reportloc + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt, a_Opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you insert the new data, but if you are writing to the same worksheet and writing to the same cells, then yes it would always override it.

Solution:
Add a new worksheet, or change the range where you write to, to avoid loss of data.

EDIT:
On your code when you add the worksheet you select the active worksheet thats why it always writes to the same worksheet you have to select the new worksheet like this:

```
a_Book.Sheets.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = a_Book.Sheets[a_Book.Sheets.Count - 1];
worksheet .Name = "You can put a name";
```

Comment: I already add a new worksheet but it writes to same worksheet again and again? I will keep on trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use Code Below:
Read the excel. Make sure it exists:

```
a_Book = a_Excel.Workbooks.Open(reportloc + ".xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Use TexttoColumns Property:

```C#
for (int i = 0; i < range.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    range.Rows[i].Value = lines[i];
    range.Rows[i].TextToColumns(
        range.Rows[i],
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
        false,
        true
    );          
}
```